# Select distinct values from group_concat results

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I'm a learner who is taking interest to learn MySQL and am building a movie site. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me out here.

So I did a query that goes like this,

```
SELECT Movie.idMovie,MovieTitle,Description,
group_concat(ActorName) AS ActorName,group_concat(DirectorName)
FROM EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Movie 
INNER JOIN EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Movie_Actor
ON EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Movie.idMovie = EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Movie_Actor.idMovie
INNER JOIN EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Actor
ON EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Movie_Actor.idActor = EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Actor.idActor
INNER JOIN EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Movie_Director
ON EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Movie.idMovie = EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Movie_Director.idMovie
INNER JOIN EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Director
ON EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Movie_Director.idDirector =
EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Director.idDirector
WHERE Movie.idMovie = 1;
```

The table I got looked like this

```
1 || Frozen || A magical movie || Idina Menzel,Kristen Bell || Jennifer Lee, Chris Buck
```

Then I queried for WHERE Movie.idMovie = 2

To my shock, what I got is this(problem is at the last cell),

```
2 || Starwars || A very nice movie || Carrie Fisher,Harrison Ford || J.J. Abrams,J.J. Abrams
```

So the problem is the group_concat doesn't work like how I thought it would. In this case for the first query it seemed fine but as for the second query it treated 1 value as a group and grouped it with itself(guessing) ? Is there any way I can group results if there are more than 1 with a ',' in-between them and if there is just 1 result then to not do anything ?

Answer (score 1):

So I realized I can fix it by including a DISTINCT function to tell the query to group only when they are different. The correct query is this,

```
SELECT Movie.idMovie,MovieTitle,Description,
group_concat(DISTINCT ActorName) AS ActorName,group_concat(DISTINCT DirectorName)
FROM EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Movie 
INNER JOIN EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Movie_Actor
ON EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Movie.idMovie = EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Movie_Actor.idMovie
INNER JOIN EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Actor
ON EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Movie_Actor.idActor = EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Actor.idActor
INNER JOIN EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Movie_Director
ON EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Movie.idMovie = EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Movie_Director.idMovie
INNER JOIN EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Director
ON EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Movie_Director.idDirector =
EAD_ASSIGNMENT.Director.idDirector
WHERE Movie.idMovie = 1;
```

Let me know if there is any way to improve this query, this seems to help me for now.  :)